# Solução: error calling Appregistry.runApplication no React-Native

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, react-native, npm

Galera, uso o **Linux Mint 19.2**.
Ao tentar executar uma aplicação React Native, via terminal, com uso do comando react-native run-android, me deparei com o **error calling Appregistry.runApplication**.

Como podem ver na figura a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na busca da solução, fiz de tudo, até mesmo reinstalar o ambiente de desenvolvimento, também tentei usar outras versões de AVD, mas nada de sucesso!

Diante de todas as observações compreendi que no Linux por um motivo que desconheço até o presente momento, o react-native não estava sendo startado quando executava o comando react-native run-android no terminal da minha distro linux. Seria necessário starta-lo em conjunto, com comandos diferentes rodando em duas janelas de terminal.

Resumidamente a solução fica a seguinte:

**1º** - execute em uma janela de terminal o comando: **sudo react-native start**

**2º** - imediatamente sem esperar o termino da execução, ou seja ao mesmo tempo em que se executa o comando anterior, rode o comando **react-native run-android**, dentro da pasta do seu projeto, usando uma segunda janela de terminal.

**OBS:** não esqueça de usar **sudo** no comando react-native start

No meu caso funcionou com sucesso.

A figura a seguir demonstra o resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]